# What was Hubie Marsten and why did he kill his wife?

Tags: stephen-king

I just finished reading "Salem's Lot" and I was sort of confused by this.

It seems that Hubie Marsten was a human allied with Barlow, much in the same way as Straker. But two things aren't clear to me:

1. What did Ben see as a child when he went into the room where Marsten hung himself? I don't think Marsten could've been a vampire, since Barlow mentions that the two never met, so how did he appear seemingly alive to Ben? Ben has a theory early in the novel about evil remaining in a place after the evildoer is gone, which I suppose means the evil could manifest in the image of Marsten, but after Ben realizes there are vampires afoot this isn't brought up again, and pretty much every other oddity going on is explained by vampires.
2. A narration about the town's secrets mentions that, unbeknownst even to the town gossips, Marsten's wife begged him to kill her. Why? This also isn't brought up again.